# How do I build breadcrumbs for an eCommerce application?

Tags: java, sql, string, netbeans, breadcrumbs

I've been working on building an eCommerce using NetBeans but I have customized most of the code suggested by the tutorials to better fit my needs. So far understanding JSTL and JAVA... I was wondering, how do I build breadcrumbs to restrain the number of products that display per page?

Example:

```
24 per page   48 per page   96 per page   View All
```

The number of products will also generate the number of pages there is to display.

For example, if there are `48 products` for that particular `category` and the user chooses to display `24 products per page`, logically the application should display `2 pages.` Anyway, you get the gist of it.

How do I go about adding that logic to my existing application? I know it has something to do with `algorithms` and probably `java.strings`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to necessarily build it yourself, there are a few frameworks out there that already have this pagination component built-in, since you mentioned you are using Java and JSTL, so I would suggest you take a look at these Java Server Faces frameworks:

- Primefaces: http://www.primefaces.org/primeui/paginator.html
- Richfaces: http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dataTableScroller.jsf?c=dataTableScroller